# Unable to generate keystore using JDK6 but able to generate using JDK5

Tags: tomcat, keystore

I am trying to generate keystore for my application using keytool command follows:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 < keystore.data.txt
```

And it's working fine with JDK5 and not working with JDK6.
FYI:

When executing with JDK5

```
Enter keystore password:  What is your first and last name?
[Unknown]:  What is the name of your organizational unit?
[Unknown]:  What is the name of your organization?
[Unknown]:  What is the name of your City or Locality?
[Unknown]:  What is the name of your State or Province?
[Unknown]:  What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
[Unknown]:  Is CN=tpserver-hostname, OU=MyCompany, O=MyOrg., L=MyCity, ST=MyState (ST), C=IN correct?
[no]:
Enter key password for <tomcat>
   (RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

When executing same with JDK6

```
Enter keystore password:  Re-enter new password: They don't match. Try again
Enter keystore password:  Re-enter new password: They don't match. Try again
Enter keystore password:  Re-enter new password: They don't match. Try again
Too many failures - try later
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correc. 'Re-enter new password' is added since JDK6. So you have to enter after password

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for my problem.

'Re-enter new password:' is new in jdk6 & jdk7 version and not asking with jdk5. So, copied and added new password under password in my 'keystore.data.txt' file then able to generate keystore file.